# Devise Ahoy track link visits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ahoy, merit-gem

Hello I have a rails app that is a closed community using devise, ahoy and merit.

We have a scaffold called resources. Each resource has a link

User model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_merit
  has_many :visits, class_name: “Ahoy::Visit”
end
```

Resources model

```
class Resource < ApplicationRecord
  has_rich_text :description
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Controller

I want to use Ahoy to track users who click through the link so that I can award points with merit for the visit.

View

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Link</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @resources.each do |resource| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= resource.title %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Learn More", resource.link, class: 'btn btn-dark btn-sm' %></td>
        <td><%= resource.category.name %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', resource %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_resource_path(resource) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', resource, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Schema

```
create_table "resources", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "link"
    t.bigint "category_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_resources_on_category_id"
  end
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :visits
  resources :resources
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations' }
end
```

How would I track the link click, and assign points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lets make a request to visits_controller when a link is clicked.
config/routes.rb
    resources :visits

controllers/visits.rb

```
class VisitsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        Ahoy::Visit.track('click', link_id: params[:resource_id])
    end
end
```

I assume ahoy.authenticate(user) is written somewhere
Lets add class resource to link and link id as data attr, so that we can bind an ajax call to visits controller carrying necessary data
view

```
<td><%= link_to "Learn More", resource.link, class: 'resource btn btn-dark btn-sm' data: {resource_id: resource.id} %></td>
```

assets/javascripts/tracker.js

```
(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() { #or whatever you used to do in your app
    $('a.resource').on('click', function() {
         that = this
         $.ajax({
             url: 'visits',
             method: 'POST',
             data: {resource_id: $(that).data('resource_id')}
         })
    })
})
```

Comment: Hi @DileepNandanam a couple of things, I am using rails 6 so the JS will need to go in a pack and the other thing is the link is not a seperate model its a column in the resources table... I will update the question to show the schema

Comment: Hi Dileep, yes but I am confused because link isnt a model, it is a column... check out the schema.... I might be missing something... but how do I use link_id on a col

Comment: to indicate link you use resource.id as link_id

Comment: ahh yes you are amazing, can you up date the js so i can mark your answer correct

Comment: and I think devise takes care of ahoy.authenticate(user) doesn't it

Comment: Not sure, im not familier with ahoy

Comment: I added the tracker.js to /app/javascript/packs/tracker.js and called import './tracker' in app/javascript/packs/application.js.

Comment: I too have a searchable and taggable collection of links which is used for collecting links to best videos they watch https://github.com/dileepnandanam/links_collection

Comment: now I am getting the error ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/ahoy/visits"):

Comment: the path should be '/visits' but not 'ahoy/visits'. you may have it wrong on tracker.js ajax call

Answer (score 2):

I'm not using ahoy so maybe my help may not be useful.

I'm not 100% you need ahoy to do that, I think it can be achieved with a clicked filed on your Resource model, updated each time a user clicked on a link.

What I will try:

in Resource_controller.rb :

```
def link
  ahoy.track "Link clicked" if params[:clicked]
  @resource = Resource.find(params[:id])
end
```

in view :

```
<%= link_to "Learn More", resource_link_path(link: resource.link, clicked: true) resource.link, class: 'btn btn-dark btn-sm' %>
```

Post your solution below if you found another one!

Comment: hi @Armand, i need to do a join table Clicked user:references resource:references because the click would need to belong to each user?

Comment: Yes, you may need a join table.

Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/a/56511343/7359370 ? This is the easiest wat to achieve your goal.